# SSRS report that allow multiple date range parameters selected

Tags: sql-server, excel, reporting-services

I am trying to create a sample SSRS report that allow multiple date range parameters selected. I was able to create the report that allow user to select to view ONE of the ReportPeriod using the query below. Now I would like to allow user to select more than one parameter and the exported Excel will have each result in a separate sheet. IN MS Visual Studio, I have set the Parameter to "Allow multiple values". How should I modify my SQL?

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
DECLARE @ReportPeriod CHAR(1)

IF @ReportPeriod='D'
BEGIN
    SET @StartDate= DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,1,GETDATE()),0)
    SET @EndDate= DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE()),0)
END

ELSE IF @ReportPeriod='W'
BEGIN   
    SET @StartDate = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,6, GETDATE()),-1)
    SET @EndDate = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE()), 6)

END

ELSE IF @ReportPeriod='M'
BEGIN
    SET @StartDate=DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0)
    SET @EndDate= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, 0)
END 

ELSE IF @ReportPeriod='X' -- Get Month To Date
BEGIN
    SET @StartDate=DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
    SET @EndDate= DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE()),0)
END 

ELSE IF @ReportPeriod='Y' -- Get Year To Date
BEGIN
    SET @StartDate=DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0)
    SET @EndDate= DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE()),0)
END 

SELECT @StartDate AS 'StartDate', @EndDate AS 'EndDate'
```

Comment: How are you going to select Muiltiple date range?? something is missing in the question?? Please show the reprot with paramenters!!

Comment: @Hiten004 The reports itself only uses 2 parameters: StartDate and EndDate as you see in the SELECT statement. When I created the report in Visual studio, I create the ReportPeriod parameter that has labels 'D','W','M','X','Y'. And depending whatever value of ReportPeriod is selected, it will set the equivalent StartDate and EndDate.

Answer (score 0):

To check for a specific value in a multi-valued parameter, try changing your comparison to

```
IF 'D' IN(@ReportPeriod)
BEGIN
    SET @StartDate= DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,1,GETDATE()),0)
    SET @EndDate= DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE()),0)
END
```

However if your report only has one Start Date and one End Date, it sounds like you'll also need to change the date parameter logic to cater for multiple periods with different start and end dates.